# How can I pass the required id via AJAX using Javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Desired Behaviour: I wish to post the job_id variable via AJAX and use it a further query to return more information relating to the job.

Problem:

1. Originally, the AJAX request would only post the job_id of the last returned row, regardless of with option I selected.
2. Since trying to fix my problem with the code below, it has just stopped posting all together.

Searching the db

```
$sql = "SELECT STUFF from THETABLE WHERE thisis LIKE '$search'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
}
```

Getting my results

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$job_id = $row['job_id'];
$job_city = $row["job_city"];
$job_title = $row['job_title'];
$pay_from = $row['pay_from'];
$pay_to = $row['pay_to'];
$job_desc = $row['job_desc'];
$list .= '<div id="widgetsearchresults" data-id="<?php $job_id; ?>"     >'.$job_id.''.$job_title.'&nbsp|&nbsp'.$job_city.'<br> From £ '.$pay_from.' To £ '.$pay_to.'<input id="jobid" type="hidden" name="jobid">'.$job_id.'</input></div>';

}
```

Posting the Job_id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#widgetsearchresults").click(function(){ 
    var url = 'thepage.php';
    var id = $(this).data("job_id");
    var postit = $.post( url, {id:id});
    postit.done(function( data ) {
});
});

});
```

Handler File:

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && $_POST["id"] != ""){

$thisjob = $_POST['idtoget'];

echo $thisjob;

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Give us a break. Show us some code! Of course we could all just blow smoke up yer kilt and make a bunch of guesses at what you have done and hope one of us stumbles on something useful to you.... Oh right, no, we got better things to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data attribute:

```
<div class="get-more" data-id="<?php $id; ?>">WHATEVER</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".get-more").click(function(){ 
        var url = 'path-to-php-handler.php';
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var postit = $.post( url, {id:id});
        postit.done(function( data ) {
            // what you echo on the php handler is returned as data -  do what you want with data
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @peteboluc. I've added a little more detail, as requested by other potential answer providers. I've updated my code using what you had provided. Still having a few issues. It's almost certainly what I have done,rather than what you have provided that is causing the problem, so thanks again.

Comment: I believe your problem lies in the fact that in your returned results you are using `id="widgetsearchresults"` it should be `class="widgetsearchresults` because as is your code is simply passing the `id="widgetsearchresults"` to the last div. using class instead of id here should resolve the issue... notice in my code `var id = $(this).data("id");` which will identify the data-id for the specific div clicked by the user.

Comment: @weehaggins ... I noticed an error in my code... i had: `$("#get-more").click(function(){` it should be `$(".get-more").click(function(){` to identify the div as a class ... sry about that

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly. I've posted my handler file above. This may be the issue. I am trying to echo the id just to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
<div class="get-more" data-id="<?php $id; ?>">WHATEVER</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".get-more").click(function(){ 
    var url = 'path-to-php-handler.php';
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var postit = $.post( url, {id:id});
    postit.done(function( data ) {
        // success action
});
});
</script>
```

and in handler file I think you want to get the id back so try this:

```
  if(isset($_POST["id"]) && $_POST["id"] != ""){

   $thisjob = $_POST['id'];

   echo $thisjob;

     }
```